# All apps show as not installed in Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, mac-app-store

It started from badge on MAS application icon showing, but MAS tells that there are "No Updates Available". Following suggestion found on the Internets, I have rebuilt the spotlight index.

Now badges are gone, but:

- I still do not have any updates
- All my purchases are listed in "Purchases" tab, with "Install" button by each one - like the apps were not installed, but they are.
- When I click "Install", MAS begins downloading, and label shows "Installed" eventually. But when I close MAS and return, I again see "Install" button, and guess - I am able to download it again. And again.

Some of the apps have newer versions for download. I still get "no updates available".

I googled for answer, but most of time I find folks having same app download from other source preventing it from being updated by MAS. In my case, there are no second copies, no pirated apps, but somehow they do not show as "Installed".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the App Store's caches and preferences? It seemed to work for a somewhat similar problem in the following link. They had a problem with updating apps as well, although they got an update button that didn't work.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4255607

Solution given from the link:

- Trash ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/Cache.db
- Trash ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist
- Trash ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.storeagent.plist
- Trash ~/Library/Cookies/com.apple.appstore.plist
- Empty the Trash to delete those files

The person with the problem also restarted their Mac after using that solution, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, I did - I've found this link already, and it didn't help. I went the extreme way, and did a clean reinstall of OS X.